# Atmel studio 7 : unrecognized option `-mrelax'

Tags: c, linker, freertos, atmelstudio

I downloaded freeRTOS Basic Example -EVK1100 from the example Gallery provided by Atmel Studio and try to build it, i got this error

```
recipe for target 'src/asf/avr32/utils/startup/trampoline_uc3.o' failed
```

the Build output gives :

```
Building file: ../src/asf/avr32/utils/startup/trampoline_uc3.s
    Invoking: AVR32/GNU Assembler : 4.4.7
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Studio\7.0\toolchain\avr32\avr32-gnu-toolchain\bin\avr32-as.exe: unrecognized option `-mrelax'
    make: *** [src/asf/avr32/utils/startup/trampoline_uc3.o] Error 1
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Studio\7.0\toolchain\avr32\avr32-gnu-toolchain\bin\avr32-as.exe" -mpart=uc3a0512 -mrelax -I "C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Studio\7.0\Packs\atmel\UC3A_DFP\1.0.53\include\AT32UC3A0512" -I "../thirdparty/freertos/demo/avr32_uc3_example/at32uc3a0512_evk1105" -I "../src/ASF/avr32/utils" -I "../src/config" -I "../src/ASF/avr32/boards/evk1105" -I "../src/ASF/thirdparty/freertos/demo/common/include" -I "../src/ASF/common/utils" -I "../src" -I "../src/ASF/avr32/boards" -I "../src/ASF/thirdparty/freertos/demo/avr32_uc3_example" -I "../src/ASF/avr32/drivers/tc" -I "../src/ASF/avr32/drivers/gpio" -I "../src/ASF/thirdparty/freertos/freertos-7.0.0/source/include" -I "../src/ASF/common/boards" -I "../src/ASF/thirdparty/freertos/demo/avr32_uc3_example/at32uc3a0512_evk1105" -I "../src/ASF/avr32/utils/preprocessor" -I "../src/ASF/avr32/drivers/intc" -I "../src/ASF/thirdparty/freertos/freertos-7.0.0/source/portable/gcc/avr32_uc3" -I "../src/ASF/avr32/drivers/pm" -I "../src/ASF/avr32/drivers/usart" -I "../src/ASF/avr32/drivers/flashc"  -g   -o "src/asf/avr32/utils/startup/trampoline_uc3.o" "../src/asf/avr32/utils/startup/trampoline_uc3.s" 
     C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Atmel Studio\7.0\FREERTOS_UC3_EXAMPLE2\FREERTOS_UC3_EXAMPLE2\Debug\Makefile(518,1): error: recipe for target 'src/asf/avr32/utils/startup/trampoline_uc3.o' failed
```

I believe that the linker complains about the option -mrelax`unrecognized option -mrelax.
[This reference](http://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/where-has-mshort-calls-compiler-option-gone#comment-1316186) shows that i have to check relax branches, but i can't find the option in my version

I wonder if there is a patch to apply to my linker so it can recognize this option or to check/uncheck some options in the project file or ....

I'am using

Atmel Studio 7 (version 7.0.934)

Windows 10

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you consider upgrading to the latest Atmel Studio, build 1006?

Comment: ok, i will update Atmel version and give you feedback

Comment: @unwind Thanks it works now

Answer (score 0):

The example project is built successfully after upgrading Atmel Studio to the last version.

To get the latest version :

help > check for updates